# Using vue-font-awesome to display a facebook icon in a Vue CLI application

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

i tried this-

```
    import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
    import { faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

    library.add(faFacebook)

    Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
```

But apparently there's no faFacebook in free-svg-icons. How to include the facebook icon?

Comment: I answered a similar question few hours ago, check it, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207263/fontawesome-error-could-not-find-one-or-more-icon/51208634#51208634

Comment: Thanks yuri! Had to use fab prefix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Solved with this:

```
terminal:
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons

main.js:
import { faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
library.add(faFacebook)

inside code:
<font-awesome-icon :icon="{ prefix: 'fab', iconName: 'facebook' }"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

check the `fontawesome-free-brands` for `faFacebookSquare`

```
import { faFacebookSquare, faFacebookMessenger } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands';
```

does that work?

---

edit

just saw that `faFacebookF` is available there too, I just missed it

`import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands';`